# Expo MailComposer does not work after building application or hosting remote

Tags: android, ios, email, expo

I am currently building an application using Expo v2.10.1 targeted for both Android and iOS but I'm having issues using `MailComposer` ([documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/mail-composer/)). I'm currently using it like this:

```
let email = "my_personal_mail@host.com"; // The email exists.
let dir = `${Expo.FileSystem.documentDirectory}data/file.txt`; // The file exists.
Expo.MailComposer.composeAsync({
    recipients: [email],
    subject: `Subject`,
    attachments: [dir],
    body: "",
    isHtml: false,
});
```

This works perfectly fine when I'm debugging on android (phone attached to computer `expo start --localhost --android`). It opens a popup where I can choose which app to send the email from and then from that app I can successfully send the email.

However, as soon as I build the application (`expo build:android`) *or* start it from remote (`expo start`) I no longer get the popup and I don't get any error messages either.

I've tried removing one parameter after the other (`subject`, `body`, etc.). but nothing has worked so far.

I do not have access to testing locally on an iOS so I do not know if it works while debugging on iOS.